# Do Meteor cursors update from background changes to the database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, cursor

I'm currently using Meteor 1.4.1 and Mongo v3.2.

I do some nightly background tasks on the Meteor server-side (by calling a method), mainly updating records. This can involve >1 million records and can take a few hours to complete.

Currently, I have a flag on the data records which is set to true when the update is complete. My code looks something like this:

```
collection: {completed: boolean, [various other fields]}

var cursor = Collection.find({completed: false});
cursor.forEach(function(record) {
   [some work]
   Collection.update({_id: record._id},{$set: {completed: true}});
});
```

My question is:

- if I were to run this task on two machines, will the cursors update
  in the background so that the two machines won't clobber each other
  and work on the same records?
- If a record is marked completed by one    machine, will the change be
  propagated to the other machine's cursor    so that that record is
  removed from its set?
- Assuming that the two machines are about the same speed, how high
  is the chance that they'll pick up the same record at the same
  time (i.e. the 2nd machine would start working on the same record
  before the 1st machine completes its tasks and marks the record as
  completed)?
- Bottomline, does this introduce too many race conditions to be reliable?

Currently my database server isn't running at capacity so ideally I'd like to spin up a few extra machines at night and run the job on all of them to finish more quickly.

My other option is to use an additional query term (maybe pass an additional term to the method) and use that to essentially divide the set of records into a slice for each machine, so that they're not picking up the same records. But ideally I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `{multi: true}` option in your update and avoid the `forEach()` loop altogether?

Comment: The problem is the [some work] portion :-) That part requires data from the record. Basically, I need to retrieve each record, use various fields to perform some calculations and create additional records in another collection. And then, when I've completed that, I can update the record as 'completed: true', and move to the next record.

If all the work was only going to update the original document, then I could probably find a way to refactor it all into a single update statement. But I process each document to create new documents in a different collection.

Comment: The [mongoDB Concurrency FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/concurrency/) may have the answers you seek. The write lock guarantees atomic updates. Furthermore " `db.collection.find()` will only return documents that match and `db.collection.update()` will only write to matching documents. I would read this to imply that you can parallelize your update operations without performing unnatural acts.